# Prove that the outer circle of the triangle $OMN$ is always tangent to a fixed line.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider a half circle with diameter $AB$.Draw the tangent $Ax$, $By$ with half circle. Take $M$ on $Ax$, $N$ on $By$ such that $AM*BN=R^2$. Prove that the outer circle of the triangle $OMN$ is always tangent to a fixed line.

[image]

---

I will $MN$ is a fixed line and $O;R$ cut $MN$ at OH is a fixed line

I see: $MN=MA+NB$ and $MN^2=MA^2+NB^2+2MA*NB=MA^2+NB^2+2R^2$

So i So I need to prove $MA^2+NB^2$ is a fixed line but i can't. Help me

Comment: What is outercircle?

Comment: What is a "fixed line"?

Comment: Sure the "outer circle" refers to the circumcircle of the triangle. A "fixed line" refers to a line that doesn't depend on the choice of the point $M$ on the line $Ax$, etc.

Comment: But then $AB$ is obviously

Comment: It's certainly obvious that $AB$ **contains** a point of the circumcircle (namely $O$). It's not obvious to me that $AB$ is the *tangent* to the circumcircle at $O$, independent of the choice of $M$, but I'm not that good at geometry, so it may be obvious to others.

Comment: You have not defined R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS.

1. $MON$ is a right triangle.
2. The circumcircle of $MON$ has its center at $K$, midpoint of $MN$.
3. Radius $OK$ is parallel to $MA$, $NB$ and thus perpendicular to $AB$.

Comment: Great ............+1

Comment: Why $OK$  is parallel to  $MA$ ?

Comment: @WordShallow By the converse of intercept theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $HO$ is the perpendicular to $MN$ from $O$.

Notice that

$$ AM \cdot BN = OA\cdot OB = R^2$$
so the triangles $AOM$ and $BON$ are similar.

From here, you obtain that the angle $MON$ is 90, and moreover $MO/MN = AO/NB = BO/NB$ so all the triangles in the figure are similar. In particular, $AO=HO=BO=R$.

Comment: How do you know M,N,H are colinear?

Comment: Prove $MN$ is tangent with half circle at $H$.

Comment: How do you find that?